# Best way to get list of child components in Blazor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor

We need to get list of child components in `OnAfterRenderAsync` method of parent component but, we don't know how to do that.
We try with `RenderBuilder` and `GetFrames` but this is always null. 
We have Splitter component with N Split Areas as child components and we need to get all areas in Parent component, in `OnAfterRenderAsync` method.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have a parent component of type X and you want to references to all tightly coupled children of type Y (for example, TabControl and TabPages) then you can do this.

1: In the Parent add a wrapper around your `@ChildContent` to add a cascading value pointing to itself.

```
<CascadingValue Value=@this>
  @ChildContent
</CascadingValue>
```

2: In your children you can consume that value via a `CascadingParameter`

```
@code
{
  [CascadingParameter]
  public YourParentComponent ParentComponent { get; set; }
}
```

3: Your children can then notify their parent of their existence

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    if (ParentComponent == null)
      throw .............("Must be used within MyParentComponent");
    MyParentComponent.AddChild(this);
}
```

If your child components are conditionally rendered then have them implement IDisposable so they can notify the parent to remove them from its list.

There's an example on Blazor University showing how to create a TabControl - https://blazor-university.com/templating-components-with-renderfragements/creating-a-tabcontrol/

Comment: @Kristijan Mihaljinac, I'd advise you to do some reading before you choose to use CascadingValue. Search in github for the issues involving the usage of CascadingValue. Here's a link to an article at the end of which you may read the conclusions arrived by the writer. No one is claiming that it is a useless approach, not at all, it is part of Blazor, but you must be aware of it's limitations and issues stem from its use. https://chrissainty.com/understanding-cascading-values-and-cascading-parameters/

Comment: The only thing you need to remember is to use `IsFixed=@true` for some extra speed. That's it.

Comment: What if the number of children changes dynamically. E.g ChildContent would look like this: `@if(checkboxValue) { <Child /> } <Child />`. How do I get the children in correct order?

Comment: You'll have to look at the data that generates them if you want to find which order they are in.